# canot find methods in SUPConnectionProfile.h

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am a beginner in native application development.I made a project using xcode.I am using SAP as my backend.Now I am trying to connect to server.For that I have set the connection properties using SUPConnectionProperties.h file for registration purpose and wrote the code for creating a local database.Now the next step ie setup synchronizationprofile is not working for me.Because the methods setServerName,setNetworkProtocol,setPortNumber and setAsyncReplay are not there in SUPConnectionProfile.h.

So what can I do to include these methods and do this step?Can anyone Please suggest any suggestions for this. I am giving the method ,having problem, here.

```
-(BOOL)setupApplicationConnection{
       SUPApplication *app = [SUPApplication getInstance];
    [app setApplicationIdentifier:@"HWC"];
    [app setApplicationCallback:self.callbackHandler];


    SUPConnectionProperties *properties = [app connectionProperties];

        [properties setServerName:@"sapeccxxx.xxx.com"];   
        [properties setPortNumber:5001];
        [properties setFarmId:0];
        [properties setUrlSuffix:@"/tm/?cid=%cid%"];
       [properties setNetworkProtocol:@"http"];

        SUPLoginCredentials *loginCred =[SUPLoginCredentials getInstance];
    [loginCred setUsername:@"ourmac"];
    [loginCred setPassword:nil];
    [properties setLoginCredentials:loginCred];
    [properties setActivationCode:@"1234"];

    if(![flightDetailsTest_Flightdetails_v1DB databaseExists])
    {
                [flightDetailsTest_Flightdetails_v1DB createDatabase];
    }
        SUPConnectionProfile *connProfile = [flightDetailsTest_Flightdetails_v1DB getSynchronizationProfile];
        [connProfile setClientId:@"0" ];
        [connProfile setDomainName:@"Development"];
        [connProfile setUser:@"ourmac"];
        [connProfile setPassword:@"password"]; 
        **[connProfile setNetworkProtocol:@"http"];**
        **[connProfile setPortNumber:2480];**
         **[connProfile setServerName:@"sapeccxxx.xxx.com"];**

     **[connProfile setAsyncReplay:YES];**


    [flightDetailsTest_Flightdetails_v1DB registerCallbackHandler:self.callbackHandler];

    [flightDetailsTest_Flightdetails_v1DB setApplication:app];

    if([SUPApplication registrationStatus] == SUPRegistrationStatus_REGISTERED)
    {

        [app startConnection:0];
    }
    else{
        [app registerApplication:0];

    }

}
```

The methods having problem are written in bold letters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the set methods you are calling do not exist (anymore) I have looked for specifications and some show the use of these methods, but no where can I find a specification of the SUPConnectionProfile. Try looking in documentation from SAP/Sybase for details specific to the version you are using.

Comment: Sorry it is not working.I have written another file which is ConnectionController.m. Inside that file only I am writing this method.My problem is the above said methods are not getting there.These methods are not there in SUPConnectionProfile.h.

Comment: I tried declaring those methods in SUPConnectionProfile.h .I dont know if it can be done like that.But then it is showing an error like 'unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b55d90' for the line: [connprofile setNetworkProtocole:@"http"];